# page not found is showing (django)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

My homepage is login page.So first it will goto the home function and if not logged in it will goto `login_user` function then after logging in it will redirected to home.But page not found is showing.Here is my code.

**views.py**:

```py
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
    return render(request, 'retest/login.html')

@login_required
def home(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.groups.filter(name='hod').exists():
         return render(request, 'retest/hod.html', {})
    elif user.groups.filter(name='principal').exists():
         return render(request, 'retest/principal.html', {})
    elif user.groups.filter(name='Rep').exists():
         return render(request, 'retest/home.html', {})
    elif user.groups.filter(name='Ajithzen').exists():
         return render(request, 'event/ajithzen.html', {})
    elif user.groups.filter(name='graphics').exists():
         return render(request, 'event/ashok.html', {}) 
    elif user.groups.filter(name='Event_incharge').exists():
         return render(request, 'event/chair.html', {})
    elif user.groups.filter(name='IEEE').exists():
         return render(request, 'event/ieee.html', {})
    else:
         return redirect('/login')
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'login^$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
```

> Page not found(404)
>
> Request Method:    GET
>
> Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead of `login^$`

```
^login$
```

Comment: still page not found..  @L_S

Comment: Do `@login_required(login_url='/login')`

Comment: But I've an doubt.Here after logged in when I press the back button it is going back to login page.How can I prevent from going back to login  page when logged in @ L_S

Comment: in `login_user` view check `if request.user.is_authenticated: return redirect("/")` on top

Comment: It works when first the page is loaded.But not working when one user logged out and again logged in. @L_S

Answer (score 0):

In default, `@login_required` will redirect the unauthenticated user to `settings.LOGIN_URL`.
`settings.LOGIN_URL` set as `/accounts/login` as default. [See the documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#login-url)

Therefore, your login url is `/login`, then you need to set the `LOGIN_URL` in setting.py file.

Add this line in the end of setting.py

```py
LOGIN_URL = "/login"
```

Also, you may want to have a look at the [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url).